# Changing URLs generated asa wrapper into set URLs

Tags: sef, wrapper

Our website generates a URL with com_wrapper - here is an example.

http://www.ifootpath.com/index.php?option=com_wrapper&view=wrapper&Itemid=39&walkID=4799

We have 652 of these and in the future it could be 1,000. I would like to generate a SEF Url Using the title of the page.

(I have sh404SEF installed)

Can this be done?

Many thanks

I had already implemented the suggestions made Max on the website when it was first published - e.g. \ Enabled Search Engine; Enabled Use URL rewriting; Renamed /htaccess.txt to /.htaccess - I have sef URLs for all other parts of my website but not those with com_wrapper URLs as mentioned in the original question....

Comment: SH404SEF uses the category / article structure to create the SEF URL. So in theory you should be able to create http://websitename/category/article-title

Comment: As I understand it these are not articles they are wrapper (iframe pages) so there is no article.

Comment: Yep, you are right. My bad. I don't really know, but I believe you are gonna have to write your own plugin. This might serve as an example https://github.com/ElectricEasel/gazebos/blob/master/components/com_sh404sef/sef_ext/com_wrapper.php  Alternatively, you could play around with some of the more advanced settings. I don't think they will help, but go to sh404sef ->control panel-> then click ->configuration. Then in General Section of the Main tab click on By Component and then browse down to Wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

You can try use SEF in Joomla:

- System >> Global Configuration;
- Enable Search Engine;
- Enable Use URL rewriting;
- Rename yor /htaccess.txt to /.htaccess

[image]

Comment: I have already implemented all the things you suggest - other URLs have sef Urls - only this with the format with com_wrapper do not have sef URLs

Comment: @Jemetos can you update your post with what you tried and the result. It wasn't obvious in your original question.

Comment: I had already implemented the suggested made Max - e.g. \     Enabled Search Engine; Enabled Use URL rewriting; Renamed  /htaccess.txt to /.htaccess  - I have sef URLs for all other parts of my website but not those   with com_wrapper URLs as mentioned in the original question....